# Finding correlations of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

**Preface**: *I am a beginner to R that is eager to learn. Please don't mistake the simplicity of the question (if it is a simple answer) for lack of research or effort!*

I have a data.table named `data` with columns labelled V1 through V20. I want to take the correlation of certain columns (1,6,7,9,10 and 11) relative to V18 such that I have a new table that looks like the following

```
Variable     Correlation_to_V18
V1              cor(V1,V18)
V6              cor(V6,V18)
V7              cor(V7,V18)
V9              cor(V9,V18)
V10             cor(V10,V18)
V11             cor(V11,V18)
```

I tried using a for loop to no avail

```
column <- c(1,6,7,9,10,11)
for (i in column) {
  correlations<-cor(data[,18], data[,as.numeric(i)])
  cor_table<- data.table(variables = colnames(data[,as.numeric(column)]), correlation_val = correlations)
  return(cor_table)
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by the column *name* `Correlation_to_V1` with the implied (inferred?) meaning that `cor(V6,V18)` is not using `V1`. Also, one cannot `return` from a `for` loop, not sure what you're hoping for in the end. Are you hoping for a new frame based on the aggregations of your real `data`? It would really help if you provided a simple/small sample frame with actual `cor` values and an actual output; it doesn't matter how you create the actual output, you can make a CSV in Excel if you'd like.

Comment: @r2evans I have corrected some errors. Im trying to find the correlation of columns 1,6,7,9,10 and 11 relative to column 18, thus the name Correlation_to_V18. In the end, I want a data table with one column listing the variables that I used to calculate the correlation to V18 and the other column the correlation value

Comment: You can get a correlation matrix of all columns pairwise with cor(data), and after that select the ones you need and name them accordingly cor(data)[c("V1","V6","V7","V9","V10"),"V18"]. The return is usually used for functions but is not necessary inside the for  loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another potential solution:

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(400), nrow = 20, ncol = 20)
data <- data.table(mat)

columns_of_interest <- c(1,6,7,9,10,11,18)
data_subset <- data[, columns_of_interest, with=FALSE]
data_cor_values <- data_subset[, .(Correlation_to_V18 = cor(.SD, V18))]
data_cor_values[, variable := columns_of_interest]
data_cor_values
#>    Correlation_to_V18.V1 variable
#> 1:          -0.049812188        1
#> 2:          -0.375566877        6
#> 3:           0.089879501        7
#> 4:          -0.022499113        9
#> 5:          -0.007267059       10
#> 6:          -0.178489961       11
#> 7:           1.000000000       18

# Trim the last row (V18)
data_cor_values[1:.N-1,]
#>    Correlation_to_V18.V1 variable
#> 1:          -0.049812188        1
#> 2:          -0.375566877        6
#> 3:           0.089879501        7
#> 4:          -0.022499113        9
#> 5:          -0.007267059       10
#> 6:          -0.178489961       11

# Check the answer is correct:
cor(data_subset$V1, data_subset$V18)
#> [1] -0.04981219
cor(data_subset$V6, data_subset$V18)
#> [1] -0.3755669
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Let's make some data (50 rows x 20 columns) that sounds like your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(corrr)

set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), 
                  ncol = 20, 
                  nrow = 50, 
                  dimnames = list(c(), paste0("V", 1:20))))
```

In general when using R, processing dataframes using loops is a bad idea. There are `apply` functions, `tidyverse` packages and other packages to make working with dataframes easier.

In this case I would use the `corrr` library to return a dataframe with the correlation coefficients. You can then filter for the term of interest `V18`, reshape the output from "wide" to "long", and filter again for the other variables.

```
correlate(df1) %>% 
  filter(term == "V18") %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:21) %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("V1", "V6", "V7", "V9", "V10", "V11"))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  term  name    value
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 V18   V1     0.125 
2 V18   V6    -0.167 
3 V18   V7     0.345 
4 V18   V9    -0.110 
5 V18   V10    0.0473
6 V18   V11   -0.0347
```

Comment: what's wrong with looping over data frames? I use apply functions on data frames all the time. Given that they are lists, I think they are perfect for looping?

Comment: I use apply functions too - they are not loops.

Comment: they are! but optimised loops.

Comment: as a matter of fact, R's vectorised operations are loops - but the loops happen on a C level. See for example https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Comment: Yes OK, I was referring to for loops, as in the original question. Can we stop this conversation now.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straight forward with the apply family. Thanks to user neilfws for the data.+1

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 20, nrow = 50, dimnames = list(c(), paste0("V", 1:20))))

stack(lapply(df[names(df)!="V18"], function(x) cor(df$V18, x)))
#>           values ind
#> 1   1.247235e-01  V1
#> 2  -3.219809e-02  V2
#> 3  -9.556828e-05  V3
#> 4  -1.912672e-01  V4
#> 5  -7.489594e-02  V5
#> 6  -1.669195e-01  V6
#> 7   3.449937e-01  V7
#> 8  -1.968900e-01  V8
#> 9  -1.099080e-01  V9
#> 10  4.732393e-02 V10
#> 11 -3.465666e-02 V11
#> 12  2.002576e-01 V12
#> 13 -4.510807e-02 V13
#> 14 -2.545680e-01 V14
#> 15 -1.679573e-03 V15
#> 16  7.318178e-02 V16
#> 17  6.446624e-02 V17
#> 18  1.999834e-01 V19
#> 19  1.120717e-01 V20
```

you loop over your data frame without the column of interest. When you decide to use lapply you will end up with a list that you can easily stack to a data frame with `stack`.

Comment: you can also make this slightly more programmatic by replacing "V18" with a variable rather than a constant